# Meteor how to save status loggedin

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have made my own login check.

```
{{#unless logged}}
    {{> login}}
{{/unless}}
{{#if logged}}
    {{> content}}
{{/if}}
```

Logged was just a session variable, but I soon realized this wasn't smart since someone could set this on the client side to true. So the logged check now also checks if a userId is set. Which is now I tested it also not secure since I can set this client side aswell. How can I make this a bit more secure?

I have just my own collection called partyUsers. Then I have a simple form which is basically this: 
    
    
    click
Then on the client I do Method.call to a server side login. That method simple check is username and password are correct. If so return true else false.

```
var User = Meteor.partyUsers.findOne({'email':email, 'password': password});
if(User !== undefined){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own package which uses amplify and does the extra login validation before the user can log in

Answer (score 0):

Use `currentUser` instead it should work all over.

```
{{#unless currentUser}}
    {{> login}}
{{else}}
    {{> content}}
{{/if}}
```

As for the security you can control the data sent down to the client via `Meteor.publish` ([docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish)) and data that can be edited via `Collection.allow` ([docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow)). You can't control someone being able to see the content but what you can ensure they can't access or alter privileged data

Comment: currentUser is from the package that Meteor provides which I can't use.

Comment: Could you give a bit more code on what you're using? I thought you're using something based on accounts-base?